# Not able to view all rows of table in Datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I was working on a code wherein I'm traversing through an XML file which contains a specific folder structure. I want to show the folder name and the files within them in table format. Following is my code:

```
DataTable dtCheckPropertyOutput = new DataTable();
dtCheckPropertyOutput.Columns.Add("Property Name");

dtCheckPropertyOutput.Columns.Add("Expected value");


string folderName = null;
string fileName = null;
// display each folder
foreach (var folder in mainFolder.Elements())
{
    DataRow anyRow = dtCheckPropertyOutput.NewRow();
    folderName = folder.Attribute("Name").Value;
    MessageBox.Show(folderName);

    anyRow["Property Name"] = "Folder";

    anyRow["Expected Value"] = folderName;


    // display each file
    foreach (var file in folder.Elements())
    {
        fileName = file.Attribute("Name").Value;
        anyRow["Property Name"] = "File";
        anyRow["Expected Value"] = fileName;
    }
    dtCheckPropertyOutput.Rows.Add(anyRow);

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dtCheckPropertyOutput;
```

The thing is that I'm able to view only the last elements from the xml, but not all the entries. For e.g. I can view File 3 and File 5 only [but not folder 1, file 1, folder2 and file 2] if the xml is as below:

```
<Root> 
<MainFolder Name="Main Folder">
    <Folder Name="Folder1">
        <File Name="File1" />
        <File Name="File3" />
    </Folder>
    <Folder Name="Folder2">
        <File Name="File2" />
        <File Name="File5" />
    </Folder>
</MainFolder>
</Root>
```

Please, someone help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. It was just a silly mistake. I'm new to C# and I'm still practicing various things. To resolve it, I just added following 2 lines just before the start of nested foreach loop and before the nested foreach loop ends.

```
dtCheckPropertyOutput.Rows.Add(anyRow);
anyRow = dtCheckPropertyOutput.NewRow();
```

I'm not sure, but please correct me and let me know if there's a better way of doing this.